# What is similar to NS Notification Center (Swift) in Flutter?

Tags: swift, flutter, dart, nsnotifications

I've used "NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("BiddingDone"), object: nil)" to post and "NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(fromBiddingVc), name: Notification.Name("BiddingDone"), object: nil)" to receive and do an action when the post object is received. PLEASE HELP ME WITH THE SIMILAR THING IN FLUTTER.

Comment: Is it something like this that you're after? https://pub.dev/packages/dart_notification_center

Comment: Seems like you are trying to learn state management? Flutter has similar stuff like ChangeNotifier. Usually this is not used by itself though. It’s usually used with something like Provider or Bloc

Comment: @Craig, I've seen it, but cannot find any tutorials on how to use it. Can you plesae share a demo code if you found one?

Comment: Sorry, man, I've not specifically used it myself ... however, if you look at their "Example", it seems quite similar to the method examples that you posted in your question (eg. there's a "post" method, there's a "subscribe" method - which I'm guessing performs the same role as "addObserver") ..... Just install it and play around?  That's what I've found I usually need to do with Flutter plug-ins